# Graph API v2.2 : user_status permission is obtained from facebook but still cant get the v2.2/me?fields=statuses data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app & user_status permission is obtained from facebook after its submitted for review. I can get the ***v2.2/me?fields=statuses*** data for the App's admin. No other fb accounts are able to get this data. When I login with facebook from my portal, the permissions requested are not shown to the users.

1. Is the issue related to FB API. I can use the obtained permissions only for the App's admin alone?
2. Is this issue related to not obtaining consent from the account while logging in from my portal. If yes, what is the method to get this done.

Anyone kindly help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review

> ...**your app's developers will be able to see, and grant, any permission without requiring review by Facebook.**

and

> **People who are listed in your app's Roles tab will have access to extended permissions without going through review (e.g. publish_actions or manage_pages).** For example, if you use the Facebook Plugin for Wordpress to publish your blog posts to your Facebook Page or Profile, you do not need to submit for review so long as all your publishers are listed in your app's Roles tab.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your swift reply. All I need is, to get the feeds of all the users, who added their fb acc through my portal. As I have upgraded to v2.2, getting read_stream permission is a nightmare. So, I decided to get atleast user_status permission from the FB team and I succeeded in that. The logged in users through my portal wont be in Roles tab / developers. So I need to get the user_status permission for all those login into fb through my portal.

Comment: Yes, you need to request `user_status` in the scope parameter of your Login URL. As far as I understood you already got the permission granted by FB, so there should be no problem with that.

Comment: Yes, 'user_status' must be passed to the scope and I understood, it must be done automatically by the fb login redirect. (Hope all permissions obtained by an app will be passed to url scope and needs to be authenticated by the user).                                                                                                                                  In my case, its not automatically done (except App Admin) & its not a good practice to force the scopes to URL because we would get different permissions at different times. Please clarify. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's never automatically done as far as I know. I don't understand why you'd think you get different permissions when using the `scope` parameter? It's in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#adding